# Why did Miep Gies write Anne Frank Remembered in English instead of Dutch?

Tags: anne-frank

[Miep Gies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miep_Gies) was one of the persons who helped Anne Frank's family and several other people hide in the "secret annex". She also managed to retrieve Anne Frank's diary after the inhabitants of the secret annex had been arrested.

Miep Gies later wrote *Anne Frank Remembered: The Story of the Woman Who Helped to Hide the Frank Family* in collaboration with [Alison Leslie Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alison_Leslie_Gold) and published it in 1987, 40 years after the first publication of Anne Frank's diary.

Miep Gies originated from Austria, not the Netherlands, but had lived in the Netherlands since the age of nine. She was fluent in Dutch by the time the Frank family moved to Amsterdam. When I read the Dutch translation of *Anne Frank Remembered*, I could not find any reason or argument in it for writing the book in English instead of Dutch. I could not find anything about this on [Alison Leslie Gold's webpage about the book](http://www.alisonlesliegold.com/?page_id=20), nor on the website MiepGies.nl (see e.g. [New edition of book by Miep Gies](http://www.miepgies.nl/en/149.html) and the [FAQ](http://www.miepgies.nl/en/faq/)). So why was the book written in English? I know that Alison Leslie Gold is American (and probably didn't know Dutch), which then leads to the question why Miep Gies collaborated with her instead of a native speaker of Dutch?

Comment: Did Miep Gies decide to write a book about Anne Frank, so she went looking for a writer, and the question is why she chose an American instead of a Dutch writer? (Couldn't the fact then there is a bigger market for books in English be reason enough?) Or was the project Gold's idea, and the question is why an American writer rather than a Dutch writer decided to write a book about Anne Frank? (Seems unanswerable.)

Comment: @user14111 Why would this be unanswerable? There may be interviews with Miep Gies (or even with Alison Leslie Gold) that provide more details.

Comment: It's probably answerable why Ms. Gold decided to do this book. Seems unanswerable why somebody else (some Dutch writer for example) didn't do it first.

Comment: If I, knowing nothing about it, had been asked to guess whether the professional writer who approached Miep Gies with a book proposal was a native speaker of English or Dutch, I would have guessed English just because a random Earthperson is more likely to speak English than Dutch. So it doesn't surprise me that the book was not written in Dutch, but I wonder why it was not written in Chinese.

Comment: @user14111 According to that reasoning, why do any non-fiction books get written in Dutch at all? The answer needs to be more specific than that.